# VBA Excel create a few new sheets with the same layout

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to create a few new worksheets at once. The problem is, that I don't know how to set the common layout for them. I used to do it separately you see below:

```
 Set asbestW = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:= _
        wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
asbestW.Name = "Asbestos Report"
With asbestW

Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
Range("B2:S48").BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium

Set LocW = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
LocW.Name = "Location Sheet"
End With
With LocW
Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
Range("B2:S48").BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
Set CivW = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
CivW.Name = "Civils"
End With
With CivW
Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
Range("B2:S48").BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
Set CabW = wkb.Sheets.Add(After:= _
         wkb.Sheets(wkb.Sheets.Count))
CabW.Name = "Cables"
End With
With CabW
Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
Range("B2:S48").BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
End With
```

I have to define these properties every time. They're very basic. I have them more, as a lot of cells are generic. Is there any way for populating several sheets with a fixed layout?

Comment: Create a template sheet (you can hide it) and copy it as often as needed.

Comment: DO you mean manually or programmatically?

Comment: Make the template manually (or programmatically but I assume it's easier manually control-wise/visually speaking). If it's to be used in several workbooks, keep it in a "template" workbook to store for future uses.

Comment: What comes to my mind is creating one worksheet programmatically and copying it across with name changing.

Comment: If your template is always the same, create it manually (and just set it to veryHidden). If you have different layouts all the time, create (or modify) the template per code. In all cases, first have one version ready and copy that. But (as you already saw), doing it by code is very tedious.

Comment: OK Thank you all for the hints. @FunThomas I think you are right. I will create (rather programmatically) the template one, which next will be duplicated across the whole workbook, but the main example will be hidden.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already got a good suggestion about how to handle this, but here's how you'd reduce the repetition in your code if you wanted to create the sheets programmatically:

```vb
Sub Testing()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook, asbestW As Worksheet, LocW As Worksheet
    Dim CivW As Worksheet, CabW As Worksheet
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    Set asbestW = CreateNewSheet(wb, "Asbestos Report")
    Set LocW = CreateNewSheet(wb, "Location Sheet")
    Set CivW = CreateNewSheet(wb, "Civils")
    Set CabW = CreateNewSheet(wb, "Cables")

End Sub

'Create and return a new worksheet named `SheetName`, after
'   applying some basic formatting
Function CreateNewSheet(wb As Workbook, SheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Set CreateNewSheet = wb.Sheets.Add(After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count))
    With CreateNewSheet
        .Name = SheetName
        Union(.Columns("A"), .Columns("S")).ColumnWidth = 0.88
        .Range("B2:S48").BorderAround ColorIndex:=1, Weight:=xlMedium
    End With
End Function
```

All of the formatting is done in the `CreateNewSheet` function, so if you change the layout there's a single place to edit your code.  Now it's no more effort to create multiple sheets than to create one.

Comment: you might want to code naming also within the `With`/`End With` block (i.e. `.Name = SheetName`) +:)

Comment: @T.M. - good point: edited

Comment: Excellent solution! Thank you!